# Scala case class. Private var not initialized

Tags: scala, case-class

I have a strange thing in my code and cannot figure the cause. Maybe is it a Scala feature that I'm not aware of.

```
case class Page(index:Int) {
  private var lines = Map[Int, Line]()

  def set(index:Int, line:Line):Page = {
    val copy = this.copy()
    copy.lines = this.lines + (index -> line) // <-- My problem
    copy
  }
}
```

My problem is that the line `copy.lines = this.lines + (index -> line)` raise a *NullPointerException* because `this.lines` is null. However `copy.lines` is not null.

Do you know why the `lines` map is initialized when I copy a `Page` but not when I create a new one ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not getting any errors from this code - are you sure there isn't some code fragment you have left out that could explain the error?

Comment: Which Scala version? 2.11 works flawlessly.

Comment: `lines` is only acceeded in this method. So there is no other code that could "nullify" the `lines`. But if it works for all of you, then it would be somewhere in my app. A kind of side effect because all of my tests are passing. Thanks

Comment: Case classes are supposed to be immutable.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing the lines variable with a immutable variable

```
case class Page(index:Int, lines: Map[Int, Line] = Map()) {
    def set(index:Int, line:Line): Page = {
        copy(lines = lines ++ Map(index -> line))
    }
}
```

You can try it out on http://www.scalakata.com/

Comment: I would like to keep this map hidden.

Comment: Then make it a private val?

Comment: ... I feel so stupid. It is not the root of my problem but it solve it anyway. (See answer for the details on the problem). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So,

The problem was due to my persitence layer. The system I'm using use java beans conventions and so it ignore the `private var lines`. Then when I restore a `Page` it set it to `null`..

One of the solutions, because I have forgotten that we can have `private val` in a case class was to create another class who expose the `lines` and map/unmap it in my persistence layer.

Hopefully, @Rovak remind me that I can also do `case classs Page(index: Int, private val lines:Map[Int, Line]=Map())`. So that I can remove all those ugly mapping lines and benefit on a cleaner approach. Another advantage is that the `set` method is more clean and don't have to modify a case class.